# Text does not scale properly when zooming out in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, browser, safari

I have an svg containing some text that you can zoom in or out. When using Chrome or Firefox the text scales properly to the point it completely disappears if you zoom out enough. In Safari when I zoom out, it scales properly up to one point, then it stays the same size, it just starts to move a bit (tested on Desktop with v.13.0.1).

It seems there is something preventing the font from getting smaller than a certain size and setting `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` does not seem to make any difference. It is not a general scaling problem in Safari, only the text, as I see other elements scaling properly. In the fiddle below there is also a red border that if you zoom out enough it disappears.

How to the get the same behavior in Safari, as in Chrome and Firefox?

Minimal example to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/5vzsLht3/2/

Problem in my personal project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPxzy.png

**javascript part (same as in fiddle)**

```js
var nodeFontSize = 16;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("height","100%").attr("width","100%")
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
            .append("g");

var text = svg.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 200)
    .attr("y", 200)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", nodeFontSize + "px")
    .text("Zoom this text by scrolling");

var bbox = text.node().getBBox();

var rect = svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", bbox.x)
    .attr("y", bbox.y)
    .attr("width", bbox.width)
    .attr("height", bbox.height)
    .style("fill", "#ccc")
    .style("fill-opacity", ".3")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  window.console && console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of having unreadable text on a website? I'm sure safari has some limits in place you can't change. So users always have readable text.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want readable text, like in this example: https://i.imgur.com/dmv6WmW.png